# Why doesn't NetBeans know my javabean property?

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, jar

I'm working on a project where I need to create a "Switch Bean" that communicates with a "Bounce Bean". I have the Bounce Bean code provided to me, I just need to make my switch bean communicate with my bounce bean. In my program, whenever I click "on", the ball needs to bounce-- when I click "off", the ball needs to stop bouncing. I have created getter/setter methods, but whenever I put my bean into NetBeans, I see no "switchOn" property. On my teachers example switchBean, you can automatically see a property called "switchOn" whenever I move it onto a JFrame in NetBeans. My bean compiles and I am able to JAR it with no problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package switchBean;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwitchBean extends JPanel
{
    private static final int LENGTH = 200;
    private static final int WIDTH = 20;
    boolean switchOn;

    public SwitchBean()
    {
        //JPanel radioButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        final JRadioButton on = new JRadioButton("On");
        final JRadioButton off = new JRadioButton("Off");
        group.add(on);
        group.add(off);
        this.add(on);
        this.add(off);
        off.isSelected();

        on.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                boolean currentStatusOfButton = isSwitchOn();
                if(currentStatusOfButton = false)
                {
                    setSwitchOn(false);
                }
            }
        });

        off.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                boolean currentStatusOfButton = isSwitchOn();
                if(currentStatusOfButton = false)
                {
                    setSwitchOn(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isSwitchOn()
    {
        return switchOn;
    }

    public void setSwitchOn(boolean switchStatus)
    {
        this.switchOn = switchStatus;
        firePropertyChange("switchOn", switchOn, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are two different projects?

Comment: Are you asking if the bounce bean is a different set of code? Yes, it is... I know how to make them communicate in NetBeans. Just don't know why my "switchOn" property isn't showing. Is there something wrong with my getter/setters? That's the only reason I could think that would stop NetBeans from know my property name.

Answer (score 0):

For bean you add implements Serializable

```
public class SwitchBean extends JPanel implements Serializable
```

After create .jar

In NetBeans in menu system do: tools -> palette -> Swing/AWT Components 
 and remove old beans and add new

Comment: I have to build my bean in a text editor, such as TextPad(what I am currently using). I am not allowed to simply build my program in NetBeans. We are learning to build Beans, not just use them.

Comment: You add library as jar of switch bean in your netbeans project ?

Comment: I just don't know what you mean by "you add library as jar of switch bean in your netbeans project?". I have added my .jar file of the switch bean to my NetBeans Project, if that's what your asking. I have JAR'd the file and added it to a NetBeans JFrame, I can see my switch and everything... it just doesn't have any properties.

Comment: Ok you insert this first of create SwitchON ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the dialect that I'm having problems understanding or what... but I do not know what you mean. Are you saying I need to add my switchBean to the JFrame before I had the bounce bean?

Comment: For bean you add implements Serializable